# how to customize magento 2 pwa studio

Tags: magento2.3, pwa

how i can customize magento 2 PWA studio

and

which best for use PWA with **magento 2**

> 1)Venia concept (PWA studio by Magento)
>
> 2)Scandipwa
>
> 3)Vue storefront

Comment: I found useful answer here [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299021/73525)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your team.

In my opinion:

- The ScandiPWA It's has been done on production, But ScandiPWA is more complex with the PHP team, you need a front-end team to know about react js, redux, node js, and graphql to develop.

Answer (score 0):

> this one useful

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298899/new-theme-on-pwa-getmediaurl-error/299021#299021

> can create new component with react and Magento PWA
>
> [https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/create-taglist-component/](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/extension-development/taglist/)
>
> tutorial
>
> https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/